# Remove directory older than x days exclude 1 directory using Windows Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
set dump_path=D:\Test
set max_days=7
forfiles /p %dump_path% /d -%max_days% /c "cmd /c if not @path==D:\path\i\want\to\ignore rd /S /Q @path"
```

I want to delete all folder and files inside which less than 7 days from today, and there is one directory that I want it to skip,
I already test the code above, but it doesn't work, can anyone help especially for the 'if not' which cannot be executed?

Answer (score 0):

```
if /i not @path==0x22D:\path\i\want\to\ignore0x22 rd ....
```

For it to work you need

- to indicate to if command that the comparision is case insensitive or be sure that case will exactly match
- both sides of the equality test must match, so, as on the left side @path returns a quoted string, on the right side it must also be quoted. 0x22 is the hex code of the quote character that can not be directly included as it will collide with the quotes around the /c "cmd /c ..."